# How to make a msgbox be a variable and trigger it on a error handler?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, msgbox

I have been working on a pet project and I was wondering how to build a more flexible way to change the message displayed on my Error Handler and save me sometime in case I decide to change it later but passing by the hustle to change all of the messages throughout my code.

Could it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

I realized a way and I would like to share it here with you guys. I am sure other insights and inputs will come all the way too and they are will be more than welcome!

In order to have the message to be more flexible I have defined several Public Const containing:

```
Public Const strGlobalErrorMsg_Title = "ERROR"

Public Const strGlobalErrorMsg_Line1 = "Sorry"
Public Const strGlobalErrorMsg_Line2 = "Make sure you entered the correct info and try again."
Public Const strGlobalErrorMsg_Line3 = "Error Number: "
Public Const strGlobalErrorMsg_Line4 = "Description: "
Public Const strGlobalErrorMsg_Line5 = "Form: "
Public Const strGlobalErrorMsg_Line6 = "Line number: "
Public Const strGlobalErrorMsg_Line7 = "me@me.com"

Public strNomeFormulario As String
```

strNomeFormulario is a string that will contain the form name coming from a string variable that would be assigned on the userform initialization, hence it is optional.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    strNomeFormulario = Me.Caption
End Sub
```

Then I created a sub only to be display the message box:

```
Sub MsgBoxError()
MsgBox strGlobalErrorMsg_Line1 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            strGlobalErrorMsg_Line2 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            strGlobalErrorMsg_Line3 & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
            strGlobalErrorMsg_Line4 & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
            strGlobalErrorMsg_Line5 & strNomeFormulario & vbCrLf & _
            strGlobalErrorMsg_Line6 & Erl & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            strGlobalErrorMsg_Line7, vbExclamation, strGlobalErrorMsg_Title
End Sub
```

And it will be called from the sub whenever it finds a error:

```
ErrHandler:
    Call MsgBoxError
```

Here is a simple test and you can create a userform or simply a button on a spreadhseet and place this code. If you opt to place it on the sheet remember the string capturing the name of the userform will be nothing.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

On Error GoTo Err_Handler:

Dim X As Integer: X = 5

Dim Y As Integer: Y = 0

Dim intResult As Integer: intResult = X / Y ' It will generate an error because no number can be divided by zero.

Err_Handler:
    Call MsgBoxError

End Sub
```

From this idea you can develop your own error handler and if you decide to change it later all you have to do is to change the Sub instead of every piece of code.

Also I have noticed I could set public constants for the msgboxes´s titles and use it on messages when transactions are OK or inputboxes.

I hope it helps somebody!